# How to slice an indexed array to obtain all elements between the first and last index?

Tags: bash-array

I have an array `tokens` which contains `tokens=( first one two three last )`. How do I obtain the values `( one two three )` if I do not know how many numbers are in the array? I want to access everything between `first` and `last` (exclusive).

`echo ${tokens[*]:1:3}`

will give `one two three` but if I do not know the length of the array how can I get all the elements after `first` and before `last`? I am looking for something similar to using negative indices in Python such as `tokens[1:-1]`

Answer (score 4):

If the array is not sparse, you can do:

```
bash-5.2$ tokens=( {1..10} )
bash-5.2$ printf ' - %s\n' "${tokens[@]:1:${#tokens[@]}-2}"
 - 2
 - 3
 - 4
 - 5
 - 6
 - 7
 - 8
 - 9
```

If the array may be sparse, you'd need to determine the index of the second element (here assuming it has at least 2 elements):

```
bash-5.2$ tokens=([12]=a [15]=b [23]=c [123]=d)
bash-5.2$ ind=( "${!tokens[@]}" )
bash-5.2$ printf ' - %s\n' "${tokens[@]:ind[1]:${#tokens[@]}-2}"
 - b
 - c
```

In `zsh` (which has normal arrays, not sparse arrays), it's just `$tokens[2,-2]`.

Comment: The key point being that Bash supports this simple arithmetic in its array indices, which was probably not known to sriganesh.

Comment: @TobySpeight, true though if it didn't support it, you could always do: `"${tokens[@]:1:$(( ${#tokens[@]}-2 ))}"`

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your version of Bash, the following should work:

```
tokens=( first one two three last )
echo "${tokens[@]:1:${#tokens[@]}-2}"
```

Result

```
one two three
```